# Java synchronous function from async function with callbacks

Tags: java, asynchronous

I have a synchronous function that looks like this:

```
void doStuff(int x, String y, Consumer<String> onSuccess, Consumer<Throwable> onFail) {
   // start something that happens on other Threads using RxJava that eventually either
   // 1) Calls onSuccess(String) or onFail(Throwable)
   // 2) returns to caller right away after starting this mess off
}
```

I want to write a wrapper around this that calls it synchronously. I've already written a class named `Result` to return to the caller. It will either have a `String` or a `Throwable` in it. What I'm trying to do is figure out how call the async function and use its `onSuccess` and `onFail` parameters to signal that the `doStuff` function should exit returning the proper `Result`.

```
Result doStuffSync(int x, String y) {
   // magic that calls `doStuff` with callbacks that enable the entire thing to run
   // within this function and build a Result
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Result doStuffSync(int x, String y) {
  BlockingQueue<Result> result = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
  doStuff(
    x, y,
    (s) -> result.add(Result.of(s)),
    (x) -> result.add(Result.failure(x));
  return result.take();
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. My solution had many more lines of code involving `Thread.join()` etc. And it didn't work -- this is so much nicer!